# Altering primary key of Django models with many-to-many relationships

Tags: django, postgresql

I have two models, `Image` and `Dataset` that are connected through a many-to-many relationship:

```
class Image(models.Model):
  id = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
  datasets = models.ManyToManyField(Dataset, blank=True)

class Dataset(models.Model):
  ...
```

I wanted to use a sequential integer as id instead of the VARCHAR. So I renamed the `id` field to `id_old`, which made Django create an integer auto-field as an id column with the following migrations like I wanted, to which I added to delete the id_old field.

```
operations = [
    migrations.RenameField(
        model_name='image',
        old_name='id',
        new_name='id_old',
    ),
    migrations.AddField(
        model_name='image',
        name='id',
        field=models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID'),
    ),
```

But the problem is that now the through table in Postgres backend has the `image_id` column with type VARCHAR, hence I get the following error if I want to add a `dataset` to an `image`:

```
operator does not exist: character varying = integer
LINE 1: ...tasets" WHERE ("app_image_datasets"."image_id" = 12764 AN...
                                                          ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Since the `image_id` field didn't get altered during these operations, I also lose the relationships between datasets and images.

So how can I alter a primary key field in a model with M2M relationships?

Comment: Do you have data in the through table that you want to keep? If not, you could remove the relationship, migrate, and then recreate it. If yes, you could try to patch the table in the database (after creating a backup) by creating an integer column, populating it with the right foreign keys and after that renaming it and adding the proper foreign key constraint.

Comment: Unfortunately I do. I ended up creating a through table, populate it, then migrate the models so they use that through table. Will write an answer to myself as soon as I can.